# Migrating A server running 2016 to another running the same

Tags: windows

I’m sure this has been answered before, but this is a new one to me. I have a server running Win Server 2016 and I want to transfer all my settings, files, and programs over easily. Including DNS and ISS settings. Is there an easy way to do this? Both server are running server 2016

Comment: What would be the purpose of migrating from server 2016 to 2016? Are you just upgrading hardware or something? There is virtually no purpose for this, you can just clone or move drives. With that said, the migration would be exactly the same as migrating from any version of Windows server to another, something that is heavily documented online already.

Comment: Sorry I wasn’t very clear I meant I’m moving to a new physical server

Comment: Then it is as I suspected. It is not typical to rebuild a server from scratch just because you’re moving to different hardware. Simply clone the drives or backup/restore to the new hardware. There is no reason to rebuild everything. Especially in a new OS like 2016. It handles new hardware robustly, but you’ll probably have to install a few drivers. Most servers are already backed up by a product that can do “bare metal” restores to dissimilar hardware. Is there another reason you want to rebuild?

Comment: My original server is getting very outdated and doesn't have enough power for my needs anymore. Is it possible to just remove all the drives and place them in order in the new server and have it boot from them?

Comment: Yes and no. It depends on the drive configuration, partition layout, RAID, etc. Assuming the new server has an entirely new disk subsystem, backing up and restoring or cloning the drives would be best. But, the OS itself should boot on the new hardware once the data is migrated properly. Then it’s a matter of cleaning up drivers. That’s why I like the bare metal restore to dissimilar hardware option of most backup programs. It aids in migrating to different hardware.

Comment: Would you suggest setting up the new server from scratch and copying the required data or just trying to clone the drives. My old server used RAID whereas my new one I've opted not to use RAID.

Comment: I’ve been suggesting a clone or backup/restore the entire time. Why rebuild for no reason? If first server is RAID and second is not. Then you should plug the second server drive(s) in to the first server and use disk cloning software to clone all the partitions as necessary to the new drives. If you have multiple drives and partitions you’ll have to use some self guidance to move everything properly. I can’t help you there.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I will try and clone each hard drive and see what I can do with that